# Automorphism group of $C_{8}\times C_{2}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

I am trying to figure how to compute ${\rm Aut}(C_2 \times C_8)$. Using GAP the answer is ${\rm Aut}(C_2 \times C_8)\simeq C_2\times D_8$.

I know that ${\rm Aut}(C_8)\simeq C_2 \times C_2$ and that ${\rm Aut}(C_2) \simeq 1 $, but that seems to have no direct relation. I would be very grateful if you could help or direct me to a relevant reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try $A=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\ 4 & 3},  B=\pmatrix{1 & 1\\ 0 & 1},C=\pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & -1}$ (the first row is reduced $\bmod 2$, the second $\bmod 8$) then $\langle A,B\rangle\cong D_8$ and $C$ commutes with them.

Comment: No, I did not. Could you please explain why these matrices need to be considered? and how they are related to the requested automorphism group?

Comment: Those matrices act on elements $\pmatrix{u\\ v} \in \Bbb{Z/2Z\times Z/8Z}$ of your group